# How to call checkbox change event before checked/unchecked in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am using [angular-bootstrap-switch](https://github.com/frapontillo/angular-bootstrap-switch) in my Angular app.

```
<input bs-switch ng-model="item.isPublished" type="checkbox" ng-change="vm.handler()">
```

I want to call an API before the switch switches its current state. The state of the switch will be changed depending upon the API's response.

The `ng-change` handler gets called after the state of the switch is changed. Is there any way by which the handler can be called before the state change?

Comment: Depends on which event you want to be fired -- otherwise how will it know to call a function on no event?

Comment: I want to catch checked/unchecked event on the checkbox. The checkbox will be checked/unchecked based on the success status of the API.

Comment: Have you tried putting your call on ngClick, and binding ngChecked to a property? (inside your function, call API and set value of that property to its response)

Answer (score 0):

For above purpose you can use ng-click

```
<input bs-switch ng-model="item.isPublished" type="checkbox" ng-click"vm.handler()">
```

From there you can change value of your model.

Comment: ng-click did not help. The function doesn't get called.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can make it more `UX` compatible way, when you click on `checkbox` it's value will change then and state of the `switch` will change, then process the request to the server, based on that response you have to decide weather the switch should be in the current state or not, other-vice user have to wait until the response to be finish.

to do this use the `ng-change`

```
<input
bs-switch
ng-model="isSelected"
type="checkbox"
ng-change="processRequest('item.isPublished')"
/>
```

in controller,

```
$scope.processRequest = function(v) {
  /*
  $http({
      method: 'POST',
      url: '/someUrl',
      data: {},
  }).then(function successCallback(response) {
      // success callback you decide the switch state is same or not.
   }, function errorCallback(response) {
       // error call back change the switch state like,
       $scope[v] = !$scope[v];
  });
  */

  //without `$hhtp` i used `$timeout` to get the asynchronous behavior. to demonstrate only, replace with your logic.
  $timeout(function() {
    console.log($scope[v]);
    $scope[v] = !$scope[v];
    console.log($scope[v]);

 }, 1500);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a custom validator:

HTML

```
<input bs-switch ng-model="item.isPublished" type="checkbox"
       my-validator="vm.handler()">
```

JS

```
angular.module("myApp").directive('myValidator', function (){ 
   return {
      require: 'ngModel',
      link: function(scope, elem, attr, ngModel) {
                ngModel.$validators.myValidator = 
                    scope.$eval(attr.myValidator);
            }
   } 
});
```

For more information see the [AngularJS ngModelController API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController).